# Tikz: consider coordinates like matrices of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to use coordinates notation, but `matrix of nodes`-like behavior to have columns adapt to width of content?

**Explaination**

I'm using tikzit to draw some plots with nodes:

[image]

However, as you can see, some nodes are really far appart (the first ones), and some others overlap. Tikzit automatically position nodes using:

```
\node[style=Z] (3) at (2,1) {$-\delta+a\pi$};
```

Of course, I could just change in tikzit the position of the nodes, but I don't like this because when I'll change the style, I'll need to change all pictures to have a proper alignment (it's actually what I'm doing right now...), and also sometimes I want to generate these pictures automatically.

So I'd like coordinates like `(2,1)` (they will all be integers) to behave a bit like `matrix if nodes`, i.e. the "column" 2 should be as wide as its widest content, plus some fixed space between columns... but of course keeping the tikzit syntax for compatibility with tikz.

Any trickery to do that?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{Z}=[minimum size=3mm, font={\footnotesize\boldmath}, shape=rectangle, rounded corners=1.3mm, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=-1.8mm, scale=0.8, draw=black, fill={rgb,255: red,204; green,255; blue,204},shape=ellipse,inner sep=0pt,]

%% picture generated by tikzit 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node[style=Z] (0) at (-1,1) {};
    \node[style=Z] (1) at (0,1) {$\alpha$};
    \node[style=Z] (2) at (1,1) {$-\delta$};
    \node[style=Z] (3) at (2,1) {$-\delta+a\pi$};
    \node[style=Z] (4) at (4,1) {\thinmuskip=0mu\medmuskip=0mu\thickmuskip=0mu$-\delta+a\pi$};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw (0.center) to (1.center);
    \draw (1.center) to (2.center);
    \draw (2.center) to (3.center);
    \draw (3.center) to (4.center);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `chain` instead?

Comment: Graphs can be more complex than chain (it's for ZX Calculus basically), they can have many inputs, outputs, loops… And tikzit allows you to copy/paste subgraphs and it's quite handy to use.

Comment: OK, but based on the example you gave, I assumed that a simple `on chain` tree would have been a suitable solution. NOw, I don't use TikZit but code directly.

Comment: Sure, I'm not blaming you ^^ Actually, I'm trying to write my own library to typeset ZX calculus based on tikzcd, and it has different advantages compared to tikzit. But I'm still interested by this question nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of absolute positions you can use `postitioning` library and place nodes relative to others.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{edgelayer}
\pgfdeclarelayer{nodelayer}
\pgfsetlayers{background,edgelayer,nodelayer,main}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{Z}=[minimum size=3mm, font={\footnotesize\boldmath}, shape=rectangle, rounded corners=1.3mm, inner sep=1mm, outer sep=-1.8mm, scale=0.8, draw=black, fill={rgb,255: red,204; green,255; blue,204},shape=ellipse,inner sep=0pt,]

%% picture generated by tikzit 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.9]
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
    \node[style=Z] (0) {};
    \node[style=Z, right=of 0] (1) {$\alpha$};
    \node[style=Z, right=of 1] (2) {$-\delta$};
    \node[style=Z, right=of 2] (3) {$-\delta+a\pi$};
    \node[style=Z, right=of 3] (4) {\thinmuskip=0mu\medmuskip=0mu\thickmuskip=0mu$-\delta+a\pi$};
  \end{pgfonlayer}
  \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
    \draw (0.center) to (1.center);
    \draw (1.center) to (2.center);
    \draw (2.center) to (3.center);
    \draw (3.center) to (4.center);
  \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Yes I know, but won't be compatible with tikzit anymore. I'm also in parallel using tikzcd when I don't care about tikzit.